# android browser dont recognize font

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

iam building a mobile web-app for android and iam using MGWT. I want to add some font style to some elements in my css file.
I have put the following font into my css.

```
font: 2.4em Futura, 'Century Gothic', ApplceGothic, sans-serif;
```

It works fine on the chrome desktop browser but not on the android browser. 
Why the android browser is not supporting this kind of font and where is a summary or an overview about all fonts which android does not support.

I changed my font into standard Times New Roman temporary.

So where could i find an overview of not supported fonts on android browser.
Could find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *Futura, 'Century Gothic', ApplceGothic* fonts in android. You can use Roboto for example.

More informations: http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html